# How can I tell if someone modified the EXIF data in a photograph?

Tags: exif

Is it possible to detect if someone modified the EXIF data in a photograph? How would someone detect that the EXIF data has been modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Can digital cameras sign images to prove authenticity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/can-digital-cameras-sign-images-to-prove-authenticity) (from http://photo.stackexchange.com) for an post about this.

There is a way to "sign" them, but as far as I know, this does (a) not work with every camera and (b) requires additional hardware like Canons [Original data security kit](http://www.canon.co.jp/imaging/osk/osk-e3/index.html)

Comment: Cool, a StackExchange on photography :-)

Comment: It also seems like would only work to show "authenticity if such signing was present", but not necessarily to show modification -- e.g. signing was stripped out as well. Also, signing an image is not necessarily the same as signing the EXIF data. Nice links, however.

Comment: Well, of course: if I just delete all EXIF tags, you can never be sure if there had been any ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can not. EXIF information is very easy to edit.

Of course, as with any file or piece of information, one could think of a signature by a trusted author (photographer) which can be verified using a public key, but this has nothing to do with EXIF itself.

See also this related question on detecting if image content has been altered:

https://superuser.com/questions/33151/tools-applications-to-detect-altered-photos